# How to organize data in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm writing an app on iOS using Swift 3 and I'm quite new to programming.

The app mimics a farm where the user can manage plants.

I'm looking for an elegant-solid way to store a quite big number of objects that will never change in the course of the application (descriptions texts, number representing the growing time of a plant, etc.).

At the moment I'm storing the informations of each plant in a dictionary where for each entry the key is a code of the plant("0","1", and so on), and the value is another dictionary where the key (I used an enum "librarySelection") represents the type of data ("description","growingTime", etc.) and the value is of type AnyObject.
For example:

```
  struct Plants {
    static let library: [String: [librarySelection: AnyObject]] = [
    "0":[
        .description: "description1" as AnyObject,
        .image: "image1.pdf" as AnyObject,
        .growingTime: 10 as AnyObject,
       ],
    "1":[
        .description: "description2" as AnyObject,
        .image: "image2.pdf" as AnyObject,
        .growingTime: 20 as AnyObject,
       ]
    ]
  }
```

This doesn't feel very handy. I looked around if there was someway to use CoreData and maybe create a pre-populated database to include with my app but that doesn't feel like the correct way either.

I'm sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Put the data into a plist or database and load the data at runtime. Do not hardcode al of the data into your code.

Comment: What's wrong with CoreData?

Comment: @Yash Tamakuwala What is the benefit in the additional overhead and complexity and learning curve of CoreData what the data is read-only?

Comment: Another option is to load the data from a json resource (either local or remote).  CoreData is probably overkill for data that doesn't change.

Comment: @Essenceofchickens, I think you are looking for ways to persist data. Using  a sqlite database with FMDB wrapper is another way. It is simpler than Core Data.

Comment: @Yash Tamakuwala I'm not the OP asking the question. Just wondering why you recommend to a newby the complexity of CoreData as the solution when there are much simpler alternatives.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html

I was scared of a pre populated CoreData database because of this: 
Only documents and other data that is user-generated, or that cannot otherwise be recreated by your application, should be stored in the <Application_Home>/Documents directory and will be automatically backed up by iCloud.

Comment: @Essenceofchickens My bad. I just wanted to know first why he thought that Core data isn't the correct way. Sure, simpler alternatives exist.

Comment: So you all would suggest the plist approach? I'm gonna need a coredata database anyway through the course of the app, because I'll have to save some other informations that the user will generate, I was just not sure about including a pre-populated one. @YashTamakuwala

Comment: Pre populated one as in? The set of files and boiler-plate code you get after checking Use Core Data while creating project?